# How to convert a string to timestamp with milliseconds in Hive

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hive

I have a string '20141014123456789' which represents a timestamp with milliseconds that I need to convert to a timestamp in Hive (0.13.0) without losing the milliseconds.

I tried this but unix_timestamp returns an integer, so I lose the milliseconds:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20141014123456789', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'))      >> 2014-10-14 12:34:56
```

Casting a string works:

```
cast('2014-10-14 12:34:56.789' as timestamp)      >> 2014-10-14 12:34:56.789
```

but my string isn't in that form.

I think I need to reformat my string from '20141014123456789' to '2014-10-14 12:34:56.789'. My challenge is how to do that without a messy concatenation of substrings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a way to avoid the messy concatenation of substrings using the following code:

```
select cast(regexp_replace('20141014123456789', 
                           '(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})',
                           '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7') as timestamp)
```

Comment: that is interesting. Can you please elaborate a bit on what you are doing?>

Comment: he uses regular expressions to modify the format of the string.
regexp_replace function offers a posibility to replace string using a special pattern language (??) called regular expression.
He then makes the groups (first 4 characters - year, next 2 - month, ...) using the brackets. For example (\\d{4}) will group first four characters into a year string which can be later addressed using $ sign and ordinal number of group, in case of year... $1.

Answer (score 2):

A simple strategy would be to use `date_format(arg1, arg2)`, where `arg1` is the timestamp either as formatted string, date, or timestamp and the `arg2` is the format of the string (in `arg1`). Refer to the `SimpleDateFormat` java documentation for what is acceptable in the format argument.

So, in this case:

```
date_format('20141014123456789', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')
```

would yield the following string: `'2014-10-14 12:34:56.789'` which can then be cast as timestamp:

```
cast(date_format('20141014123456789', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS') as timestamp)
```

The above statement would return timestamp (as desired).

Answer (score 1):

i had the date field in this form **2015-07-22T09:00:32.956443Z**(stored as string). i needed to do some date manipulations.
the following command even though little messy worked fine for me:)

```
select cast(concat(concat(substr(date_created,1,10),' '),substr(date_created,12,15)) as timestamp) from tablename;
```

this looks confusing but it is quite easy if you break it down. 
extracting the date and time with milliseconds and concat a space in between and then concat the whole thing and casting it into timestamp. now this can be used for date or timestamp manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a column 'birth_date' in your table which is in string format,
you should use the following query to filter using birth_date

```
date_Format(birth_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssSSS')
```

You can use it in a query in the following way

```
select * from yourtable
where 
date_Format(birth_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssSSS') = '2019-04-16 07:12:59999';
```

Comment: How could i leverage this to take precision upto 9 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done without being messy. Because according to the unix_timestamp() function documentation it returns the time is seconds and hence will omit the milliseconds part.

**"Convert time string with given pattern to Unix time stamp *(in seconds)*, return 0 if fail: unix_timestamp('2009-03-20', 'yyyy-MM-dd') = 1237532400."**

Best option here would be to write a UDF to handle this is you want to avoid messy concatenations. However the concatenation (though messy) would be better to the job.

Comment: I like the UDF approach better because I can utilise the Java SimpleDateFormat.  Why do you think concatention is better? Is the UDF going to be slower?