# Hive create table statement for timestamps that aren't in a 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' format

Tags: hive

I have a JSON dataset in HDFS that contains a timestamp and a count. The raw data looks like this:

```
{"timestamp": "2015-03-01T00:00:00+00:00", "metric": 23}
{"timestamp": "2015-03-01T00:00:01+00:00", "metric": 17}
...
```

The format of the timestamp almost matches the Hive-friendly 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format but has a couple of differences: there's a 'T' between the date and time. There's also a timezone offset. For example, a timestamp might be `2015-03-01T00:00:00+00:00` instead of `2015-03-01 00:00:00`.

I'm able to create a table, providing that I treat the timestamp column as a string:

```
add jar hdfs:///apps/hive/jars/hive-json-serde-0.2.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `log`(
  `timestamp` string, 
  `metric` bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde" WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp"="$.timestamp", "metric"="$.metric")
LOCATION 'hdfs://path/to/my/data';
```

This isn't ideal since, by treating it like a string, we lose the ability to use timestamp functions (e.g. `DATE_DIFF`, `DATE_ADD`, etc...) without casting from within the query. A possible workaround would be to [CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) and [CAST the timestamp using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355194/how-to-convert-a-string-to-timestamp-with-milliseconds-in-hive), but this entails copying the data into its new format. This seems inefficient and not in the spirit of 'schema-on-read'.

Is there a way to create a schema for this data without processing the data twice (i.e. once to load, once to convert the timestamp to a true timestamp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to decide whether to:

- do CTAS as you described
- push the conversion work/logic into the consumers/clients of the table

For the second option this means including the string to timestamp conversion in the sql statements executed against your external table.